# Datetime is not Json Serializable in Matplotlib Error

Tags: python, matplotlib, mpld3

I have Implemented a Matplotlib graph ,that plots correctly,However when I try to implement the same onto the browser using mpld3 module,I get an error sayin datetime is not Json Serializable,I did search on Google ,however couldn't exactly find what I was looking for.My code is below:

```
  connection = MySQLdb.connect ()

  # prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
  cursor = connection.cursor ()

  # execute the SQL query using execute() method.
  cursor.execute ()

  #fetch all of the rows from the query
  data = cursor.fetchall()
  ddt =  sorted(set(data))

  qwe = []
  for date in data:
      qwe.append(date[0]);  

  def generate_dates(start_date, end_date,dte):
  x= []
  a= []
  d= []
  td = datetime.timedelta(hours=24)
  current_date = start_date
  i = 0
  j = 0
  x.append(0)
  while current_date <= end_date:
      if str(current_date) in dte:
          x[j] += dte.count(str(current_date))
      else:
          x[j] += 0
      if i % 7 == 0:
          a.append(current_date)
          j = j+1
          x.append(0)
      current_date += td
      i = i+1
  return x,a
start_date = datetime.date(2017, 07, 26)
end_date = datetime.date.today()
#generate_dates(start_date,end_date,qwe)
x,a = str(generate_dates(start_date,end_date,qwe))


y = range(len(x))
plt.plot(x,color='green', linewidth = 2,marker='o',  markerfacecolor='blue', markersize=8)
plt.ylabel('Number of Bookings')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.xticks(y,a,rotation = 90,fontsize = 8)
mpld3.show()
```

This is the error that I get: 
"datetime.date(2017, 7, 26) is not JSON serializable"

Comment: please give some information about variable `qwe`

Comment: Edited with the whole code.

Comment: The same error is triggered when placing a `plt.text()` when the x-axis are datetimes. Funnily enough, placing a `ax.axvline()` with a datetime coordinate for x does not result in such an error.